# Specify date format when updating date field in mongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I am using mongoDB 3.4 and want to close documents in a mongoDB collection by setting an `EffectiveEndDateTime` field to todays/current date time and want it in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

How can I specify the date format?

My current update query is:

```
db.stores.update({
    "storeID": "P0925"
}, {
    $set: {
        "EffectiveEndDateTime": Date()
    }
}, {
    "multi": true
})
```

Thanks

Comment: well.. AFAIK that's already the default format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add new keyword to Date in your query

```
db.stores.update({"storeID" : "P0925"}, {$set : {"EffectiveEndDateTime": new Date()}}, {"multi" : true})
```